# R plot from function is empty

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my attempts to pass in a state such as 'AZ' as the parameter it prints an empty plot. I'd like the function to be dynamic in that sense where I can look at the plots for various states using their abbreviation instead of looping to print all the plots simultaneously. The title needs to be dynamic as well.

Thanks!

```
Plotbydistrictbystate <- function(st){
       myplot <- ggplot(subset(queryResults, queryResults$state == "st"), 
                 aes(x=districtGUID, y=Proportion, fill=Page)) +
                 geom_bar(position = "fill",stat="identity") + 
                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
                 scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + ggtitle("Plot of st")
print(myplot)
}
Plotbydistrictbystate(AZ)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like a small fix.But this works.

```
Plotbydistrictbystate <- function(st){
    myplot <- ggplot(queryResults[queryResults$state == st,], 
          aes(x=districtGUID, y=Proportion, fill=Page)) +
          geom_bar(position = "fill",stat="identity") + 
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
          scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + ggtitle(paste("Plot of", st))
    print(myplot)
}

Plotbydistrictbystate("WI")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Plotbydistrictbystate <- function(st){
       myplot <- ggplot(queryResults %>% filter(state == st), 
                 aes(x=districtGUID, y=Proportion, fill=Page)) +
                 geom_bar(position = "fill",stat="identity") + 
                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
                 scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + ggtitle(paste("Plot of", st))
       print(myplot)
}
Plotbydistrictbystate("AZ")
```

Comment: I get this error : Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class mts/ts
I tried doing the filter in a separate function then using that dataframe but same results.

Comment: What does `queryResults` look like?

Comment: Added the picture above. 
Appreciate the time and help!

Comment: Can you post a subset of the data using `dput`, so that we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thank you but I got it figured out! Appreciate it.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: Apparently all I had to do was call the function with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your function does not do anything with the input argument... maybe try something like:

```
Plotbydistrictbystate <- function(st){
       myplot <- ggplot(subset(queryResults, queryResults$state == as.character(st)), 
                 aes(x=districtGUID, y=Proportion, fill=Page)) +
                 geom_bar(position = "fill",stat="identity") + 
                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
                 scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + ggtitle(paste("Plot of",st))
print(myplot)
}
Plotbydistrictbystate(AZ)
```

Keep in mind that an error might occur in the conversion to character...

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'AZ' not found

Comment: I think the function call should be `Plotbydistrictbystate("AZ")`.